# Problem with subimport command in LyX

Tags: lyx, external-files

I have the following structure (folders in *italics*)

> - master.lyx
> - *parts*
>
>   - *mst*
>
>     - mstCh1.lyx
>     - *preamble*
>
>       - packages.tex
>       - preamble.tex
>   - *p1*
>
>     - p1Intro.lyx

Each lyx file imports `preamble.tex` located in `parts/mst/`:

- `master.lyx` using `\subimport{parts/mst/preamble/}{preamble}`
- `mstCh1.lyx` using `\subimport{preamble/}{preamble}`
- `p1Intro.lyx` using `\subimport{../mst/preamble/}{preamble}`

It allows me to compile the files either on their own or from `master.lyx`, `where mstCh1.lyx` and `p1Intro.lyx` have been added as Child Documents.

`preamble.tex` contains among other things `import{./}{packages.tex}`

For strange reasons, everything works as expected except `p1Intro.lyx` which can not be compiled due to

```
\subimport{../mst/preamble/}{preamble} LaTeX Error: 'preamble.tex' not found.
```

even though the relative path is correctly set.

Using currfile does not help since the returned folder is always empty...

Any idea?

**Edit**
After some tests I did this morning, it seems the relative path `..` is not correctly interpreted. I just sent an email to the package's author, and update this post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a workaround and will edit this answer with the answer of the package's author.

Instead of using a `..` in the `\subimport` command, I am simply using a symbolic link to the folder I am trying to reach.

In my current configuration :

- I have created a symbolic link called `preamble` in the folder `p1` pointing to `../mst/preamble` with the shell command (Linux): `ln -s ../mst/preamble/ preamble
- I am importing the `preamble.tex` file in `p1Intro.lyx` with `\subimport{preamble}{preamble}` which is now working! Moreover, it allows me to use the same command as the one used in the file `mstCh1.lyx`.